# Removing ambiguity from context free grammars

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

Given an ambiguous grammar, to remove **operator precedence** problems we would convert the grammar to follow the operator precedence rules. To solve the **operator associativity** problem, we convert the grammar into left recursive or right recursive by considering the operator it is associated with.

Now when the computer has to do the parsing, suppose if it uses the recursive descent algorithm, **should the grammar be unambiguous in the first place**? Or the grammar should have different requirements according to the algorithm?

If the grammar is left recursive, the recursive descent algorithm doesn't terminate. Now how do I give an unambiguous grammar(with associativity problems solved) to the algorithm as the input?

Comment: Recursive descent isn't very good at parsing expressions. There are other simple techniques (Pratt parsers, for example), or you can use an LR(1) grammar, possibly with precedence declarations if your parser generator handles them, as most do.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar must be LL(k) to use the standard efficient recursive descent algorithm with no backtracking. There are standard transformations useful for taking a general LR grammar (basically any grammar parsable by a deterministic stack-based algorithm) to LL(k) form. They include left recursion elimination and left factoring. These are extensive topics I won't attempt to cover here.  But they are covered well in most any good compiler text and reasonably well in online notes available thru search. Aho Sethi and Ullman Compiler Design is a great reference for this and most other compiler basics.

Comment: but my question is how left associativity is solved?

Comment: Look up left recursion elimination and left factoring. These are fairly complex transformations covered well in many places. It's not worth a long SO article to repeat all this.

Comment: @desireprg It's no problem to parse left associative expressions with a right recursive rule. The idea that recursion in rules encodes associativity is not correct.